# How can systems recognize different wifi AP with the same SSID and MAC address

Tags: wifi, wpa2

I'm testing, for studying purpose, an evil twin attack. In my scenario I have both the rogue AP made by my laptop and the real AP with the same SSID and MAC address, but with different security protocols (the rogue one is open, while the real one has WPA2) and optionally different channels.

Now, with both APs working on the same channel, it seems that different systems have different capabilities of recognizing both of them, or only one. I have 3 systems:

-on Windows and Android I can see and connect to both

-on Linux Slackware, networkmanager can only see the real one, and even if that is shut down, it starts seeing the rogue one, but can't connect to it

How is this possible? What parameters are used to know that there are two different networks, and not only one with two APs?

Answer (score 1):

It's the **Security** parameter.

From experience, if you make the rogue AP's security protocol  as same as the real AP with the same `key`, the clients will connect to the rogue AP when the real AP shuts down.

Comment: Shutting down the real AP is not possible, I just want the Slackware system to recognize that there are two different networks and show up both

Comment: @Requiel: To a client, if the SSID and security params are identical, there is only *one* network and the client will roam across the APs back and forth, based on link performance (which is not necessarily "strongest signal" and seems to be implementation-dependent). That's not a bug, that's a feature. I suspect that splitting this into two networks would require significant changes in client's association and roaming code.

Comment: But, my security parameters are different. The rogue ap has no security at all while the real one has WPA2. Still on slackware I can't see both

Comment: I don't know about slackware but maybe it depends only on SSID & MAC to display available networks, so you won't see both networks.